# Encrypting db for SQLCipher Issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, fmdb, sqlcipher

I'm having problem with creating a new encrypted db.
I've done research regarding about this and these are some solutions that I have tried.

Using terminal 
based on http://sqlcipher.net/design/

```
sqlite3 sqlcipher.db
sqlite> PRAGMA KEY='test123';
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t1(a,b);
sqlite> INSERT INTO t1(a,b) VALUES ('one for the money', 'two for the show');
sqlite> .quit

~ $ hexdump -C sqlcipher.db
```

running the hexdump still gives me non encrypted db text.

Doing the attached way to existing Db in ios.

```
- (void)encryptDB
{
    sqlite3 *unencrypted_DB;
    NSString *path_u = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] 
                        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"unencrypted.db"];

    if (sqlite3_open([path_u UTF8String], &unencrypted_DB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Database Opened");
        // Attach empty encrypted database to unencrypted database
        sqlite3_exec(unencrypted_DB, "ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY '1234';", NULL, NULL, NULL);

        // export database
        sqlite3_exec(unencrypted_DB, "SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');", NULL, NULL, NULL);

        // Detach encrypted database
        sqlite3_exec(unencrypted_DB, "DETACH DATABASE encrypted;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

        NSLog (@"End database copying");
        sqlite3_close(unencrypted_DB);
    }
    else {
        sqlite3_close(unencrypted_DB);
        NSAssert1(NO, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(unencrypted_DB));
    }
}
```

No issues running above, but encrypted.db is not appearing in my documents folder.

After setting up the ssl and sqlcipher in my application. 
Using this

```
- (void) openCipherDB
{
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] 
                              stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"unencrypted.db"];
    NSLog(@"database path %@", databasePath);
    sqlite3 *db;
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //sqlite3_exec(_db, "ATTACH DATABASE 'xyz.sqlite' AS encrypted KEY 'test';", NULL, NULL, &t)
        const char* key = [@"secret" UTF8String];
        int sqlite3_key(sqlite3 *db, const void *pKey, int nKey);       //i added this after seeing SO
        sqlite3_key(db, key, strlen(key));
        if (sqlite3_exec(db, (const char*) "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // password is correct, or, database has been initialized
            NSLog(@"database initialize");
        } 
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"incorrect pass");
            // incorrect password!
        }

        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
}
```

it gives me the NSLog of incorrect password and of course my db is not encrypted too.

what else can i do to encrypt my db?
thanks.

Comment: With regard to your command line example at the top, did you build SQLCipher, or were you running the existing SQLite binary?  You would need to build SQLCipher and run the generated sqlite3 binary from the build in order for that to work.  Are you certain in your iOS project that you were using the SQLCipher version of the library  versus SQLite?

Comment: how did you get this solution. After buying the sql cipher?

Answer (score 4):

The first problem you have is running sqlite3 instead of ./sqlite3. You need to provide the explicit path to the sqlcipher version of sqlite3 or you'll end up using the one installed as part of your OS, which doesn't support encryption.

For the second issue, you must provide the full path to your encrypted.db in the attach (e.g. the same way you create the full path for unencrypted.db) using stringByAppendingPathComponent.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen.  Your second comment fixed the issue for me.

Comment: "provide the full path to your encrypted.db in the attach" was the trick in my case, Thanks.

Comment: @Stephen Lombardo I have another problem in transition to newer sqlcipher version [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682940/transition-from-cipher-2-0-to-3-0-fails-error-26-on-attempt-to-read)

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the second issue of attaching the database. I was confused on how to use the solution provided by Stephen , as I couldn't figure out how to give the full path into the sql statement as it accepts only `const char`, finally I came up with the below code and it worked, posting the same here

.......................

```
NSString *sql1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ATTACH DATABASE '%s' AS encrypted KEY '%s'",[encryptedDBPath UTF8String],"1234" ];
NSLog(@"String is %@", sql1);
sqlite3_exec(unencrypted_DB, [sql1 UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

....................................

-anoop